# Sorting word C language from a .txt file: \n "space" undectable

Tags: c, tabs, conditional-statements, fopen, fgetc

I'm trying to code a little program to sort words frome a .txt file.
I use Dev-C++ 5.11 as IDE with GCC 4.9.2.

Below, the .txt file content:
**aaa ert ert ert**
**zzzz**
**aaa**
**zzzz**

**#**
**ert**
**ert**
**#xxx**

I have to store a single word by line, skipe empty lines and lines starting by "#".

I tried several things and I can't get why it's not working

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TML 50
#define TMF 255

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){  
    
    float argv0 = atof(argv[0]);
    float argv1 = atof(argv[1]);
    float argv2 = atof(argv[2]);
    
    char dict[strlen(argv[2])]; //contient filename pour pointeur fichier

    FILE *df, *rf; //init pointeur de fichier
    
    char out, line[TMF][TML] = {{0},{0}};//tableau contenant toutes les lignes
                    
    int i=0, j=0, nbrL=0, skip=0; //variable de contrôles

    if(strcmp(argv[0], "wordcount") == 0 && strcmp(argv[1], "dictfile") == 0)
    {   
        strcpy(dict, argv[2]);
        printf("%s \n", dict);
        df = fopen(("%s", dict), "r"); //ouverture du fichier
        
        if(df!=NULL){           
            do{
                do{ // 32:' ' 10:\n  35:# 
                    if(line[i][j-1] == atoi(" ")){
                        skip = 1;}      
                    else if(line[i][j-1] == atoi("\n")){
                        skip = 1;}  
                    else if(line[i][j-1] ==atoi("#")){
                        skip = 1;}
                    else{
                        skip = 0;}
                    
                    out = fgetc(df);
                    line[i][j] = out;
                    
                    printf("(%d)", line[i][j]); 
                    j++;
                }while(skip != 1);
                //printf("(%s)", line[i]);
                i++;
            }while(out != EOF);
            
            nbrL=i;
            fclose(df);
        }   
        else
            printf("Error in opening file");
    }
    else
        printf("Command unknown or invalid arguments\n");   
        
        
    printf("\n-----------------------------\n");

    return 0;                                       
}
```

Below, what the above code gives:
[program results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9wiL.png)

According to you, what is my mistake if it is indeed a mistake on my part?

Comment: What should be the expected result?

Comment: The result should display a single word by line and avoid " " and "#"